# pgfplots + unicode-math + lualatex gives the error "kernel/command-already-defined"

Tags: pgfplots, luatex, unicode-math

With the following MWE compiled with `lualatex`, I get the error:

```
...
LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
Control sequence \crampeddisplaystyle already defined.
...
l.637 \um_new_cramped_style:N \crampeddisplaystyle
```

and the same error for `\crampedtextstyle`, `\crampedscriptstyle`, and `\crampedscriptscriptstyle`. Switching the loading order of `pgfplots` and `unicode-math` fixes the problem, as does compiling with `xelatex`. Prior to the most recent update of `pgfplots` (v1.12), this error was not present. How can I fix this error?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\listfiles
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Relevant listings from `\listfiles`:

```
pgfplots.sty    2015/01/31 v1.12 Data Visualization (1.12)
unicode-math.sty    2014/06/30 v0.7f Unicode maths in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
```

Comment: You always need to set a math font, `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}` will give you the standard latex font. But should not solve the problem.

Comment: luatex primitives are enabled in prefix form so `\crampeddisplaystyle ` is undefined but `\luatexcrampeddisplaystyle` is defined as a primitive, but the new pgfplots is defining the unprefixed forms, which is probably a mistake, or at least unicode-math isn't expecting it. You could undefine them easily enough but it depends why they were defined in this update..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug that has been fixed in pgfplots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pgfplots unintionally defined additional unprefix forms of such macros. I have already fixed this in the developer version of `pgfplots` (thanks to the helpful remark of @DavidCarlisle).

Switching the load order (`unicode-math` before `pgfplots`) is currently the most simple work-around (known to me).

Comment: Thanks Christian! I have two more (what I suspect are) bugs to report about `lualatex` and `pgfplots` - would you prefer I emailed you, or posted them here on TeX.SX?

Comment: Bug fixes are probably better sent to me; they are of limited use to the community once they are fixed. So please: sent an email!

Comment: Still seeing this error in v1.12. In which version was it supposed to be fixed?

Comment: It is fixed in 1.12.1